¿Como hacer una consulta o query sobre un cursor en VFP?
Tengo la siguiente query que traigo desde base de datos:
      text to mycadena textmerge noshow
            select 
            codigo,
            fecha
            from librod             
            order by librod_copy.referencia desc
            endtext       
        n=sqlexec(xconector,mycadena,'XLIBROD')

A medida que recorro un cursor x, quiero hacer una query o consulta sobre ese mismo cursor.
Por ejemplo:
select codigo, fecha from XLIBROD where codigo=x.codigo

Algo así quisiera obtener, y despues recorrerlo con un do while !EOF() ese registro.
Lo que deseo, es que en primera instancia, guardo en un cursor llamado XLIBROD,
despues trabajar sobre ese cursor haciendole query o consultas para recorrerlo y obtener sus valores.
Desde ya, gracias.
